# Disqus deleted comments are syncing with wordpress but active comments do not

Tags: plugins, functions, comments, disqus, sync

And the sync is also not being automatic, I have to go in the Sync Comments option.

I've tried almost everything and none of them worked. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Disqus Comments:

[image: enter image here]

Disqus comments synchronized with wordpress. As you can see, all comments have already been deleted from Disqus and none that is active is synchronized. And is not syncing all the deleted comments, just a few.

[image]

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script>
        /**
         *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
         *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
         */

        var disqus_config = function () {
            this.page.url = '<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>';  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
            this.page.identifier = '<?php dsq_identifier_for_post($post); ?>'; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
        };

        (function() {  // REQUIRED CONFIGURATION VARIABLE: EDIT THE SHORTNAME BELOW
            var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

            s.src = '//mysite.disqus.com/embed.js';  // IMPORTANT: Replace EXAMPLE with your forum shortname!

            s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
            (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
        })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>

<!-- Comments count on each post -->
    <span class="disqus-comment-count comments" data-disqus-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#disqus_thread"></span>

<!-- JavaScript on footer -->
    <script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//mysite.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
```